# bzr unable to connect to ssh host (because of python?)

Tags: python, ssh, bazaar, openssh

Until today, I have been able to use `bzr pull server:path/to/trunk`, but today I get an error:

```
Unable to connect to SSH host server; EOF during negotiation
```

It is not clear why this error occurs, but this is the traceback from `~/.bzr.log`

Any ideas about how to fix this?

```
Mon 2011-02-21 16:36:04 -0600
0.022  bazaar version: 2.1.1
0.022  bzr arguments: [u'pull']
0.026  looking for plugins in /home/user/.bazaar/plugins
0.026  looking for plugins in /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/plugins
0.062  encoding stdout as sys.stdout encoding 'UTF-8'
0.133  opening working tree '/home/user/pecan'
0.178  ssh implementation is OpenSSH
0.697  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 853, in exception_to_return_code
    return the_callable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 1055, in run_bzr
    ret = run(*run_argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 661, in run_argv_aliases
    return self.run_direct(**all_cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 665, in run_direct
    return self._operation.run_simple(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/cleanup.py", line 122, in run_simple
    self.cleanups, self.func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/cleanup.py", line 156, in _do_with_cleanups
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/builtins.py", line 993, in run
    possible_transports=possible_transports)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/branch.py", line 169, in open
    possible_transports=possible_transports)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/bzrdir.py", line 843, in open
    return BzrDir.open_from_transport(t, _unsupported=_unsupported)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/bzrdir.py", line 873, in open_from_transport
    redirected)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/transport/__init__.py", line 1644, in do_catching_redirections
    return action(transport)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/bzrdir.py", line 860, in find_format
    transport, _server_formats=_server_formats)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/bzrdir.py", line 1820, in find_format
    return format.probe_transport(transport)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/bzrdir.py", line 1830, in probe_transport
    format_string = transport.get_bytes(".bzr/branch-format")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/transport/sftp.py", line 435, in get_bytes
    f = self.get(relpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/transport/sftp.py", line 425, in get
    f = self._get_sftp().file(path, mode='rb')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/transport/sftp.py", line 397, in _get_sftp
    connection, credentials = self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/transport/sftp.py", line 389, in _create_connection
    self._host, self._port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/transport/ssh.py", line 376, in connect_sftp
    self._raise_connection_error(host, port=port, orig_error=e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bzrlib/transport/ssh.py", line 252, in _raise_connection_error
    orig_error=orig_error)
SocketConnectionError: Unable to connect to SSH host server; EOF during negotiation

0.698  Transferred: 0KiB (0.0K/s r:0K w:0K)
0.698  return code 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused because I had added

```
alias bzr status='bzr status -V'
```

to `.bashrc`, and `bzr status` is an invalid alias name that presumably confused the server's bzr

A [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/593149) to bzr indicates that a similar error can be caused by changes to the server's firewall settings

Comment: BTW. you could use bazaar's own aliases to alias in the `-V`:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.dev/en/user-guide/using_aliases.html